# Is there a way to save the pdf created from blade straight to database as a pdf file?

Tags: laravel, pdf

I have created a pdf file of the bill that the customer can download. What i want to do is save the same pdf in my database without having to download it first and then upload again. Is there a way to do this?

Controller:

```
public function export(){
         $user = Auth::user()['id'];
            $now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
            $wherecond = "  userid=".$user." and created_at like '%".$now."%' ";
            $bill = DB::table('cartitems')->select('cartid','category','menu','price','created_at')->whereRaw($wherecond)->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();

            $whereconditn = "  userid=".$user." and created_at like '%".$now."%' ";
            $cost = DB::table('cartitems')->whereRaw($whereconditn)->sum('price');
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('/pages.bill', ['bill' => $bill, 'cost' => $cost]);
            return $pdf->stream('bill.pdf');
    }
```

Here i have created a pdf on blade bill.blade.php and the user can download the file but can i save the same pdf directly to the database without downloading it for admin part?

Answer (score 1):

You can add BLOB type in your database to save PDF. But it's not the best practice due to the amount of storage that is required.

I suggest you the following process :

Step 1) generate your PDF file

Step 2) save your PDF file on your webserver

Step 3) create a link (URL) to your PDF file

Step 4) save link (URL) in your database

Comment: i am using localhost for now. i just need to know how i.e. a line of code maybe to save the said pdf after i have created it. cant i do it in my controller to save said pdf??